# Automate note addition to "Google keep"

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, google-keep

i want to automatically add selected text , right click and add it as notes to keep. tried applescript but javascript doesn't seem to have good option to add notes directly.

similar to 
[Mimic onclick events in Google Keep with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193147/mimic-onclick-events-in-google-keep-with-javascript)

Any suggestions?